# Power Apps, Close opened URL after Launch

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a button that launches a URL, I do this to give my users access to the SharePoint List backend. I want to close this newly launched tab.

How can I do this?

Here is my button formula:

```
Navigate(BrowseScreen1, ScreenTransition.None); Launch("link")
```

Comment: Are you trying to close the (newly opened) browser tab using Power Apps formulas?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Power Apps capabilities.

You cannot close the (newly opened) browser tab using Power Apps formulas as this is something specific to browser behavior/activity.